# In a make file, how do I flatten or iterate over a multi-line list?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have something along the lines of

```
define URLS
http://www.foo.com/
http://www.bar.com/
http://www.foo1.com/
endef
```

How can I flatten that so that it uses spaces instead of linefeeds (I've tried tinkering with $(subst) with little luck) or iterate over each item with a for loop? I realize I can define it differently, but was hoping for a nice clean one-item-per-line solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to define `\n`, because you can't use it literally.

```
define \n


endef
```

Now one may use `subst` as follows:

```
URLS := $(subst $(\n), ,$(URLS))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nicely-spaced := $(strip ${URLS})
```